# When in component lifecycle should I get query params from URL?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm using React 16.4.1, React Router 4.3.1, and React Redux 5.0.7. I have a search route that can receive a query param like this:

https://example.com/search?q=foo

To be clear, React Router 4 [discontinued support for `location.query`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4410), so we're left having to manually parse query params from the `location.search` prop that React Router provides. We can use something like Javascript's `URLSearchParams` interface for this.

So I'd like a user to be able to visit the URL above and immediately begin a search for "foo". Therefore, I need to gather the `q` param at some point during page load. But when?

My first instinct was to have my `Search` component parse the query params during its `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook. That also happens to be the recommended hook for retrieving data from the server, something I'll do if the `q` param has a value.

But I've also considered moving that logic outside the component entirely to some JS file that generally runs on page load, like my app's `index.js` file. I have access to my Redux store there and could update the application state with the "searchText", and my `Search` component could then simply check for that prop (wired via Redux) during its mounting.

Gathering query params from the URL on page load - then taking action on them - is a relatively new problem for React developers, given that React Router handled it for us prior to version 4. But surely I'm not the first person to have to do this since version 4 was released. Is there an established pattern or best practice for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not aware of best practices, if they even exist for this situation, but I do it in `componentDidMount`. That's the earliest lifecycle event that should be used

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Incidentally, if you were to fetch server data in `componentDidMount`, would you also update the state (search results in my case) in that same method, or a different lifecycle hook?

Comment: Same lifecycle. But make sure you make it synchronous if your state manipulation relies on data from your api

Comment: I mistakenly gave search results as an example - those are being retrieved asynchronously using redux-thunk, and redux is handling storing the results in my application state. We're a little off topic, but to clarify, I actually was thinking about when I'd store the "searchText" into a local component state, once I've parsed it from the query param. Is `componentDidMount` an acceptable place to update local component state?

Comment: From how I'm interpreting what you're asking, that's not possible. `componentDidMount` only fires once when the component mounts. Your search text will never change unless you remount your ui element that renders that text, which is a terrible idea. I suggest storing that searchtext data in redux. No need for lifecycle events when you do it that way, because redux will take care of all that business for you.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to create an initialize folder along actions, reducers etc.. and create there functions like

```
export default (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(urlQueryParams());
    // Some other initializers
};
const urlQueryParams = () => {
    // return json to reducer with the params
}
```

Then on your main index file you can trigger it

```
import addQueryParamsInitialzer from 'redux/initialize/queryParam';

const store = configureStore(INITIAL_STATE);
addQueryParamsInitialzer(store.dispatch, store.getState);
```

That way you'll have it on your store no matter what component you're on

Comment: What does this accomplish that regular actions in a react lifecycle can't do?

Comment: It's more like a hoc.. just that it will be called always and before everything.. in some cases like the one above it is really useful to take the action out of the react life cycle

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's useful to take this functionality **out of** the React component lifecycle?

Comment: You might want those query params on different spots of your app. I think it's not react related but more of a general app initializing related.. you'll be able to get them everywhere easily that way.. since you don't get it as global parameters on v4, you'd want it globally somehow and since you are using redux it's easy to dispatch it to the store.
Also, if you'll change your app to be ssr you'll be able to load it on your initial state and no hard refactoring will be needed.
But then again, it's my point of view.